# Azure AD: Need to validate id_token received with access token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I'm doing authorization with Azure AD (using `/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`) with these scopes:

```
openid email profile https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read
```

In response, I get an id_token and an authorization code.  I ignore this id_token and use the authorization code to get an access token (using `/oauth2/v2.0/token`)

When I get the access token, I again get an id_token along with it.

The [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-tokens) state:

> When your app receives an ID token, it must validate the signature to prove the token's authenticity and validate a few claims in the token to prove its validity.

But since my app received the ID token based on its own HTTPS post to a Microsoft server, is it safe to use the ID token without validating it?

Answer (score 0):

According to what you have described,

1. You are using OpenID Connect
2. You are using the [hybrid flow](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#HybridFlowSteps) (with `response_type=code id_token`)

If you are not expecting an id token from authorization request, you can use use other either [Authorization code flow](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#CodeFlowSteps) or [Implicit flow](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitFlowAuth)

These flow types are selected from **response_type** parameter and not from claims.

For authorization code flow,

**`response_type=code`**

For Implicit flow,

**`response_type=id_token token`** or **`response_type=id_token`**

Note that, implicit flow does not produce an access token and is intended for JavaScript or similar clients which cannot protect a refresh token.

Once you get the id token from the token endpoint or from authorization endpoint(based on implicit flow), you can validate it just once.

Comment: Hi KcDoD, yes, that all sounds right, but I don't want to change my flow.  I just want to know if it is safe to use the second id_token (received with the access token) without validating it.

Comment: @JeffO'Neill If you are not using that for your client authentication, ignoring it would be safe. But make sure you get exactly the same id token from both requests (not in the code, but these services being new could have bugs in them). Anyway, I suggest to change flow if you are NOT using the hybrid flow intentionally. You could save few bytes by not receiving the unused id token.